# .on() jQuery click function won't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a simple click function into my jsfiddle but it isn't working.

Here is my javascript/jquery:

```
$(document).on("click", "#introPic", function () {
    $("#introduction").addClass("hide")
    $("#q1").removeClass("hide")
});
```

I don't understand because it works if i take the element in question (`#introPic`) out of the divs it is nested in and place it at the top of the document. This isn't a solution because it ruins all the html/css formatting.

Does `.on()`only work for un-nested IDs?

Here is the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/JosephByrne/HdPq4/2/

And here is the amended version with the `#introPic` moved to the top of the html - http://jsfiddle.net/JosephByrne/kRudM/

Comment: YOU'VE FORGOT TO TERMINATE LINES WITH  ";"   (:

Comment: in fact your `#content` was put behind the `body`, it's because of `z-index:-99`, so actually you cannot click on the `#introduction`

Comment: @num8er no, `;` is optional

Comment: $(function(){$(document).on("click", "#introPic", function () { $("#introduction").addClass("hide"); $("#q1").removeClass("hide"); });});

Comment: Your first fiddle doesn't even have the chunk of jQuery you posted in your question.

Comment: Thanks @KingKing i've changed the z-index and it's working now - if you add it as an answer i'll accept

Comment: @JosephByrne you're welcome, I've just added my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine. The problem is the `#introduction` is put behind the body element because of `z-index:-99` you set on the `#content` which is the container of the `#introduction`. So clicking on any element in `#content` will actually click on the body element. Just remove the `z-index` and it should work fine.

The interesting thing here is the background of the body should cover the `#content` but it happens only when you specify some background for the `html` element.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click", "#introPic", function () {
        $("#introduction").addClass("hide");
        $("#q1").removeClass("hide");
    });
});
</script>
```

Your code does not work cuz you've forgot to terminate lines with semicolons.

Comment: I didn't downvote the right answer; I downvoted your answer, which isn't right. The solution was posted as a comment above by King King.

Comment: Ok. Next time please write WHYs right after downvoting. :)

Comment: I'm using Mobile phone so I don't see whole picture of problem. To check it. So plz excuse me. I was wrong.